# Can't connect to FTP using IP with KNetAttach

Tags: debian, ftp, remote-access, dolphin-file-manager

I work on Debian/KDE and i use the remote folders to upload my files through FTP. This has worked flawlessly for a long time until now.

I am migrating some websites to a new VPS and until i switch the nameservers i can only work with the IP on the new server. So i tried to create remote folders with KNetAttach to upload the files, but it is not working. Says authentication failed (!!!).

I tried logging in through the address bar in the browser (iceweasel/firefox) and it worked fine. The same login credentials work fine when i login to cPanel.Server support said he could connect through Filezilla as well. But it just won't cooperate when i try with the remote folder.

The connection through IP works fine for my other server, i tested it.

I tried a restart of my PC and i get the same thing. What could be wrong?

Comment: Perhaps KnetAttach only attempts active FTP, while your other clients are using passive mode

Comment: It does work with my other server though. In that case, shouldn't it not work with it either?

Comment: If your other server was behind a firewall configured to masquerade active FTP?  Total speculation.   You could set up tcpdump and watch what happens when you try. Alternately, attempt to connect with command line FTP, and see if it fails data transfer in active mode, but works in passive

Comment: If it's your server, you should be able to look at the FTP server's  logs and see if it's failing to establish a data connection

Comment: If it is a FTPS server, and it tried to authenticate TLS, and didn't have a god certificate for a raw IP address, I could see that giving some sort of AUTH error too

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it. The problem was special characters like ë, ç and @ which i was using in the password. I removed these and it worked.